# dose not show icon in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, bundle

I'm working on a project using ASP MVC, for showing data I have used kendo.
When I publish the project on IIS the icon of Kendo grid dose not load and I have bundled CSS and JS. Without bundling would be better. I do not know what to do?

I have published in IIS without bundling
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AoDv.png)

I have published in IIS with bundling
[show iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyR0E.png)

and I have tested to enable and disable the following line but it did not work;

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it is because of folder references inside kendo css file. Have a look to files like `kendo.bootstrap.min.css` in your `kendo` folder in your solution explorer.For example may be you need change `Bootstrap/sprite.png` to `2016.3.914/Bootstrap/sprite.png` based on your kendo folder refrence in your project.